# Checking for presence of array in parameters

Tags: javascript

I am currently checking for an array in the parameters passed to a JavaScript function.
The arguments can be of type:

```
1. function(a, b, c, d)
2. function([a, b, c, d])
3. function([a], b, c, [d, e, f], g)
```

I need to check if the parameters are contained in a single array or not. The following code works for case `1.` and `2.` but not for `3.` :

```
if (Array.isArray(args)){
  // section A
}
else{
  // section B
}
```

This code is considering `3.` to be an array, though it has mixed values, it is entering section A instead of B. I want it to enter section B. Only arguments surrounded by `[]` completely should go in A.

Comment: does my answer still not do what you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the only argument is an array or none of the arguments are an array:

```
function foo(args)
{
    var v;

    if (arguments.length === 1 && Array.isArray(args)) {
        v = args; // grab vector (B)
    } else if (arguments.length >= 1 && ![].some.call(arguments, Array.isArray)) {
        v = [].slice.call(arguments, 0); (A)
    } else {
        throw "begone, evil caller";
    }
    // do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [**arguments**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object. Iterate through the `arguments` object and check each *parameter* passed like

```js
test(1, 2, 3, 4);
test([1, 2, 3, 4]);
test([1], 2, 3, [4, 5, 6], 7);

function test() {
  var onlyArray = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if (!Array.isArray(arguments[i])) {
      onlyArray = false;
      break;
    } 
  }
  if (onlyArray) {
      snippet.log('section A');
      // section A
    } else {
       snippet.log('section B');
      // section B
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Based on your updated question

See the again updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3djw6cn/3/):

```
function containsOneArray(test) {
    return test.length === 1 && Array.isArray(test[0]);
}

function yourFunction() {
    if(containsOneArray(arguments)) {
        console.log(true); 
    } else {
       console.log(false); 
    }
}

yourFunction(['hello']); // true
yourFunction(['i', 'am', 'cool']); // true
yourFunction('hello'); // false
yourFunction(['a'], 'b', 'c', ['d', 'e', 'f'], 'g'); // false
```

## New Answer

Added some separation of concerns (see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3djw6cn/1)):

```
function containsArray(_args) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(_args),
        contains = false;

    args.forEach(function(arg) {
        if(Array.isArray(arg)) {
            contains = true;
            return; // don't need to keep looping
        }
    });

    return contains;
}

function yourFunction() {
    if(containsArray(arguments)) {
        console.log(true); 
    } else {
       console.log(false); 
    }
}

yourFunction(['hello']); // true
yourFunction('hello'); // false
yourFunction(['a'], 'b', 'c', ['d', 'e', 'f'], 'g'); // true
```

What this does is gives you a utility function to just check if the `arguments` object passed into `yourFunction` contains an `Array` anywhere.

## Old Answer

Check out the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3djw6cn/):

```
function containsArray() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        contains = false;

    args.forEach(function(arg) {
        if(Array.isArray(arg)) {
            contains = true;
            return; // don't need to keep looping
        }
    });

    console.log(contains);

    if(contains) {
        // do something   
    } else {
       // do something else   
    }
}

containsArray(['hello']); // true
containsArray('hello'); // false
containsArray(['a'], 'b', 'c', ['d', 'e', 'f'], 'g'); // true
```

Comment: I actually need to return `false` for the third case. Need to return `true` only if all the parameters are in one array.