# How to check if passed parameter is an array of arrays

Tags: javascript

I need to allow only vectors like `function([a, b, c, d])` or `function(a, b, c, d)` to my program. I need to write a unit test that gives a syntax error when I get parameters of the form `function([a, b][c, d])` and `function([a][b][c][d])`.

Note that I am not looking for just an array here. I need to filter out multiple arrays and only take in single dimensional array (or no arrays at all)

How can I check the existence of such parameters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you check if a variable is an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767486/how-do-you-check-if-a-variable-is-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @Bik This is not a duplicate of the question you have referenced. In addition to it being an array, I need to check if its multidimensional.

Comment: None of your examples features an array of arrays. Note: There are no multidimensional arrays in JS, only arrays of arrays.

Comment: How exactly does this differ from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30970398/checking-for-presence-of-array-in-parameters)?

Comment: In my previous question, I was looking for ([a], [b]) whereas, now I need to write a specific unit test case for an input of the type ([a][b]). The former is a valid input whereas the latter isn't. I want to throw a more specific error to the user of the function.

Answer (score 0):

If your function always takes one or more arguments, You can check by testing `Array.isArray(arguments[i])` .

Answer (score 0):

```
function myMethod(param){
    if(param instanceof Array)
    {
        // check that no element is an array
        return !param.some(function(item){
            return item instanceof Array;
        });
    }

    return false;
}

console.log(myMethod([1,2,3,4])); // true
console.log(myMethod([1,2,3,4, [1,2]])); // false
```

I don't really understand how you have an input that can be `a,b,c,d` and `[a,b,c,d]` - What is your prototype?

Comment: I am writing a function that calculates the mode of a list of items. It should return the number(s) that occur the most in a set of values.

Comment: What is the function's prototype?

Answer (score -1):

you can always check its children if it is array or not

```
x = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];
if(Array.isArray(x))//true since x is a array
    if(Array.isArray(x[0])) //true since x[0] is array
        console.log('x is two dimensional array')
```

Comment: @downvoter can you please explain the reason for downvote

Comment: Though I did not downvote your answer, but I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for. Instead of `x = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];`, I'm looking for detection of the type `x = [[1,2,3][4,5,6]];` (without the comma)

Comment: x = [[1,2,3][4,5,6]]; is not valid in javascript except if it is a string